# jQuery each not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slider with 10 slider elements. However, only 7 out of 10 elements are rendered, given my data structure contains 20 sets. The site is hosted [here](http://bit.ly/1aS33nQ)

The code in question

```
function populateCarousell(cdata) {
    var x = 0;  //debug
    jQuery(".wslide-slides .wslide-slide").each(function() {
        var single = cdata.shift();
        var jcurrSlide = jQuery(this);
        jcurrSlide.find(".wslide-caption-text").text(single.title);
        jcurrSlide.find("a").attr('href', "https://carousell.com/p/" +single.id);
        jcurrSlide.css({'background-image':Base64.decode('dXJs')+'('+single.primary_photo_full_url+')'});
        jcurrSlide.css({'background-image':'contain'});
        jcurrSlide.css({'background-position':'50% 50%'});
        jcurrSlide.css({'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});
        x++;  //debug
        jcurrSlide.find(".wslide-slide-inner2").removeAttr('style').find("img").css({'display':'none'});
    });
    alert(x);   //Outputs 7
}
```

which is activated by (to ensure page fully loaded)

```
function caroDataCallback(data) {
    if(document.readyState != "complete" ) {
        setTimeout(function() { caroDataCallback(data); }, 2000);
    }
    else{
        populateCarousell(data);
    }
}
```

Upon examination in Chrome, the results is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because your page is not fully loaded when you call `populateCarousell(cdata)` function in your javascript file. Try instead of using `$(document).ready()`, use the `$(document).load()` to make sure all the images are loaded before you initiate your carousel.

*Update*: Use `$(window).on('load', function() { .. });` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated with trigger code. Code contains checks to ensure page fully loaded. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Actually, .load() has been deprecated that way. It should be $(window).on('load', function() {  ... }.

Comment: Tried your method. Now doesn't seem to even be loading at all.

Comment: I made a small typo by the way - $(window).on('load', function() {populateCarousell();});. I see $(document).load() is now used on your page but that is incorrect code.

Comment: Ok now it's back to 6 items instead of 10

Comment: Using the .on() method is preferred to listen for the load event. The code on your page is now jQuery(window).load(function() { ... }) which again is deprecated. If it still persist when using .on(), the issue must lie somewhere else than window onload.